# onViewDetachedFromWindow or onDetachedFromRecyclerView equivalent in ListView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I need to remove a Firebase Listener when the app closed or a fragment with a ListView was detach, in RecyclerView the approach is usually set the adapter to null to call `onViewDetachedFromWindow()` and `onDetachedFromRecyclerView()` but how to do it in  ListView specially when my listener is inside BaseAdapter? I prefer to use ListView for a specific libary.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can remove the listener according to your activity life-cycle.

Comment: My scenario is different, I will update my question.